# trying to log into character ai using my facebook account, and i keep getting this error?

Tags: facebook

[This is the error i keep getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DoALT.jpg)

So i made a character ai account using my facebook account, and for a while it was going fine, i could log in and chat with the characters, but now i get this error whenever i try to log into character ai using my facebook account.
I've tried to close the app, and restart my mobile phone, and to check the app permissions, but i still get the error, i would like to know if there is a way to fix this, because i am literally sobbing right now because i can't get to my account on character ai, since i only created my account through my facebook account, help, please

Answer (score 0):

Mine is doing the same thing! I’m trying my best to just wait it out lol

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).